# Fit cartesian coordinate system to point cloud

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a cloud of points that initially lie in a plane and have a coordinate system attached to them. I then displace the points slightly, and I want to find how a 'best fit' of the coordinate system moves with the points.

If the points originally lie in the x-y plane, I can find the new z axis with a best fit to the plane using singular value decomposition (although this may not be the best way). What should I do about the x and y axes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points