# Why does the SVD method minimize the sum of the squared point-plane distances?

Tags: svd, plane-geometry

I have a set of $N$ points $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ and I need to find the best plane fit to them. So far I've been numerically minimizing the sum of the *absolute valued* point-plane distances:

$$f(a, b, c, d)= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{|ax_i + by_i + cz_i + d|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$$

which works. But recently I found out about the [singular value decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99317/37846) method, which as far as I understand, analytically minimizes the *squared* point-plane distances:

$$f(a, b, c, d)= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(ax_i + by_i + cz_i + d)^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$

Keeping in mind that *I am not a mathematician*, could you explain step by step why (or how) the SVD method minimizes the squared point-plane distance?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I actually come from that question (is linked in my question)

Comment: If you want, open a chat room and let us discuss.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer @ClaudeLeibovici, I was doing some reading on the topic. Here's the chat room if you are still interested in discussing: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68709/why-does-the-svd-method-minimize-the-sum-of-the-squared-point-plane-distances