# Fitting a plane to 4 points: analytical and iterative solutions resulting in poor fits

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, computational-mathematics

I have the following set of 4 Cartesian coordinates:

`coords = [3.64811 7.61531 9.05108; 3.53604 4.82801 9.05108; 3.53604 4.82801 6.34192; 3.64811 7.61531 6.34192]`

I am trying to fit a plane of the form $ax+by+c=z$ to these 4 coordinates. I tried both the analytical least-squares solution, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points), and an iterative approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552011/3d-curvefitting/18648210#18648210). These both result in relatively high root-mean-square-errors but I am not sure why. Using the curve fitting toolbox in MATLAB results in an $r^2$ that's negative and notes that the equation is badly conditioned, although visually the resulting fit looks okay somehow (image below).

It is rather intuitive what the plane *should* be. What can I do to get a more accurate solution? Mathematically, what is the issue with this set of coordinates?

[image]

Comment: In general, four points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ don't have to be [coplanar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity).

However, in your case, there does in fact exist a plane that contains all four points (additionally, your four points are the vertices of a rectangle that is not a square, but this is not directly relevant).

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. I'm mainly confused because in this case, as you correctly mentioned, the four points are the vertices of a rectangle, so there should be not only a *good* planar fit but a *perfect* fit.

Comment: Can you show the MATLAB code you used to get the least squares fit?

Comment: The above figure was done using the GUI, so I don't have the code for that (I did the rest in Python). But something like the following should replicate it: `pinv(A'*A)*A'*B` to get a column vector with $a$, $b$, and $c$, where `A = horzcat(coords(:,1),coords(:,2),ones(4,1))` and `B=coords(:,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the four points lie on a plane that is vertical. i.e. you can write it as

$$2.78730x-0.11207y-9.3149292113 = 0.$$

So you won't be able to fit a plane of the form $$ax+by+c=z$$ to these points.

Comment: My end goal is to get the unit normal to the plane that would go through the points. What would be the best way to do so in this circumstance?

Comment: If a plane can be written in the form $ax+by+cz=d$, then the vector $(a,b,c)$ is normal to the plane. Alternatively, you can take the cross product of two vectors in the plane which aren't parallel or anti-parallel.

Comment: Oh, of course. Yes. That's simple enough. Thank you for your insight.