# Fit a plane to a set of 3D points by not using explicit function

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, least-squares

I have a set of 3D points $\mathcal{X} = \left\{x_1,\ldots,x_N \right\}, x_i = (x_i^1, x_i^2, x_i^3)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and I want to find a plane $c_0 x^1 + c_1 y^2 + c_2 x^3 + c_3 = c^T x = 0$ which is close enough to all points, but I want to avoid expressing one coordinate as function of the other ones.

I was setting up a least square problem, I defined $f : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$
f(c;\mathcal{X}) = \frac{1}{2N}\sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} \left( c^T x_i \right)^2
$$

Derivative with respect to $c$ gives

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} x_i x_i^T c 
$$

setting such derivative to $0$ however gives me a trivial solution $c = 0$, therefore my strategy now was to impose a rank condition on the matrix $A(\mathcal{X}) = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} x_i x_i^T$ so I can get a non trivial solution, however I'm not sure how to do this, but I'm fairly sure there's a known expression to this problem which I cannot find.

Can you help?

It would be really helpful if you could also show the proof and not just the final formula/algorithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Fitting Plane given a Set of Points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points)

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure. Does SVD minimize the distance? I think it's a known fact, but where does this come from?

Comment: What's "the distance"?

Comment: @joriki Distance point plane.

Comment: I don't understand. Which point? You have a set of points. I thought you were trying to minimize the sum of the squares of their distances from a plane.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Total_least_squares_minimization. Minimizing $|An|$ under the constraint $|n|=1$ using a Lagrange multiplier yields $An=\lambda n$, and then since $|An|=\lambda|n|$ the minimum is achieved for the smallest eigenvalue. (In the present case $n$ is the normal vector of the plane and $A$ is the matrix of coordinates of the points.)

Comment: To allow the trivial solution you can use the condition $c_0^2+c_1^2+c_2^2=1$