# finding best fit surface passing through points using RBF or bspline methods

Tags: geometry, interpolation, python, spline, radial-basis-functions

I have some points in 3D (x, y and z) and want to fit a surface through them. I prefer to use bsplines for finding the best surface among my points. My final goal is the equation of the surface. I have read [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points) but still I have no idea how to find the equation when my points are are not linearly arranged. I mean I may have points that are like a bowl. In advance, I do appreciate any help to make such an algorithm in python.

Comment: You need to define what is best fit. Minimal squared root error?

Comment: Dear @Moti, thanks for your help. I need surface passing through points but not a simple linear surface. I want somthing like bspline or thin plane or RBF methods.

Comment: You also need to define what kind of surface is desired. Otherwise there are too many possibilities.

Comment: Dear @HandeBruijn, thanks for your feedback. I want a surface which is passing my points. Something like bspline or rbf or thin plane methods do.

Comment: @Ali_d: The hints you've been given all point to [scipy.interpolate.bisplrep()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html).  So, use that.