# Why is SVD on $X$ preferred to eigendecomposition of $XX^\top$ in PCA?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, principal-component-analysis

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3871/1543) J.M. has mentioned that ...

> In fact, using the SVD to perform PCA makes much better sense numerically than forming the covariance matrix to begin with, since the formation of $XX^\top$ can cause loss of precision. This is detailed in books on numerical linear algebra, but I'll leave you with an example of a matrix that can be stable SVD'd, but forming $XX^\top$ can be disastrous ...

Could you elaborate on why the calculation of $XX^\top$ is disastrous for the matrix given in that post? I calculated $XX^\top$ for the numbers it specifies. I got a $3\times3$ matrix with all $1$'s.

Comment: This post apparently refers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca).

Comment: I changed your title to reflect the question more precisely. Please feel free to roll back if you think the change is inappropriate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alright, to further explain Läuchli's example in detail:

The precise problem with forming the cross-product matrix in this case is that you have effectively made a **singular** matrix out of your starting matrix.

In exact arithmetic, the cross-product matrix of the Läuchli matrix should have looked like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1+\varepsilon^2&1&1\\1&1+\varepsilon^2&1\\1&1&1+\varepsilon^2\end{pmatrix}$$

Its *exact* eigenvalues are $(3+\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^2)$. The trouble with **inexact** arithmetic is that if $\varepsilon^2$ is tiny, then $1+\varepsilon^2$ is the same as $1$, and you now have the spectrum $(3,0,0)$. **You do think there's a difference between $\bf \varepsilon^2$ and $\bf 0$, don't you?**

The good thing, then, about direct SVD algorithms is that it is able to compute these tiny singular values accurately, much better than taking the eigensystem of the cross-product matrix. Here's a *Mathematica* comparison:

```
lauchli = With[{ε = 1*^-20},
               N[{{1, 1, 1}, {ε, 0, 0}, {0, ε, 0}, {0, 0, ε}}]];

SingularValueList[lauchli, Tolerance -> 0]
   {1.73205, 1.*10^-20, 1.*10^-20}

Sqrt[Eigenvalues[Transpose[lauchli].lauchli]]
   {1.73205, 0. + 1.82501*10^-8 I, 0.}
```

(A similar demonstration could of course be done in MATLAB; luckily this example is built-in there, as `gallery('lauchli', n)`)

Now, we even have a spurious (but tiny) imaginary component in the second answer; neither of the last two results matches the first.

That's why the SVD is vastly preferred.

Comment: +1. I used (and referenced) your example in my answer to the almost identical question on CV: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79043. You might be interested in adding something to that discussion.