# Numerically stable SVD

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359397/why-svd-on-x-is-preferred-to-eigendecomposition-of-xx-top-in-pca) regarding SVD, it is explained why eigen decomposition of $ A^tA $ is not numerically stable compared to "direct SVD algorithms".

Since the former is the algorithm I'm most familiar with, my question is,

out of all algorithms for SVD out there (some of which can be found for example [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf)), which "direct" algorithm would you use if you had to implement numerically stable SVD, using the  **fixed point arithmetics** (say in c++, you only use *shorts* and can't use *floats* or *doubles*)

Comment: What do you mean by *direct*? Are not all the SVD algorithms iterative, unless for matrices of fixed size.

Comment: @uranix It was a quote from the mentioned question. by "direct" I meant without initially calculating $ A^tA $

Comment: Years of research and experience is required to write an algorithm for computing the SVD. To write an algorithm using shorts is very difficult if not impossible. You have to do a lot of scaling; otherwise there will be accuracy issues and overflow and underflow problems. The standard data type for the SVD is the double.