# Why is SVD stable when eigendecomposition is not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca/3871#3871), it is stated that

> In fact, using the SVD to perform PCA makes much better sense numerically than forming the covariance matrix to begin with, since the formation of $XX^\top$ can cause loss of precision

Why is this the case? Isn't $XX^\top$ just a matrix multiplication, what makes this operation so disastrous?

Comment: This has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359397/why-is-svd-on-x-preferred-to-eigendecomposition-of-xx-top-in-pca); see also [this stats.SE question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79043/why-pca-of-data-by-means-of-svd-of-the-data).

Comment: Because the singular bases are orthogonal while the eigenbasis does not have to be, and so can be arbitrarily close to a non-basis.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but the singular values are Lipschitz continuous but the eigenvalues need not be. See https://mathoverflow.net/q/88132/31729

Comment: This specific question (not the title) is just about the instability created by multiplying out $A A^T$ or $A^T A$, and in these cases the eigenbasis you want to find is orthogonal anyway.